# Databinding to multiple textboxes with single data source

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, binding

I'm working on a program that is interacting with a simple Access database. When the form loads there need to be multiple text boxes that are bound to the same table and field in the database, Inventory_Table.Quantity, to display the quantity of the inventory. From there, orders are read into the system adjusting the inventory as necessary.

I need to specify what row these are each supposed to be bound to, because right now it is binding them all to row 0, which makes sense but is not what I want. Is this possible? Heres the code I have to bind currently.

```
   txtTopQuantity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myDS, "Inventory_Table.QUANTITY"))
   txtLegQuantity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myDS, "Inventory_Table.QUANTITY"))
    txtFastenerQuantity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myDS, "Inventory_Table.QUANTITY"))
    txtShortQuantity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myDS, "Inventory_Table.QUANTITY"))
    txtLongQuantity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myDS, "Inventory_Table.QUANTITY"))
    txtWheelQuantity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myDS, "Inventory_Table.QUANTITY"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure as i've never seen binding specifying the row before.

The way I would do this though if this is not an ASP.Net application would be to create a class containing all your items and bind to that, or adjust the data so that it is returned with 1 column per thing you want to bind to. This way I feel you have more control over your data, it may be just personal preference but I have always done it this way.

Other than this you could have the textboxes added dynamically, for instance use whichever control suits your needs, then create an item template that has a label and textbox. set the itemsource of your outer control to the dataset, and bind the txtbox to the Quantity column, then bind the label to something you can use as a description of what the textbox is.